# Cannot Update Provisioning Profile on Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, testflight

I am using testflight to provide users with access to my team's mobile apps. 
We want to add a new device to the provisioning profile for one of our apps. We successfully updated the provisioning profile on the Apple Developer site, but when we log on the "Permissions" tab for our app in testflight, the option to "Update Profile" is no longer available like it used to be. The only available option for the Provisioning Profile is to "Remove Updated Profile". Any insight on how to add the updated provisioning profile to this app to give access to new users would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Due to the changes in iOS 8, it's no longer possible for testers to install provisioning profiles from the iOS Settings app. App developers will now need to rebuild their Ad Hoc beta apps to update the embedded provisioning profile in the app's IPA file."

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829818-adding-more-testers-to-a-build-

Answer (score 1):

Apple broke this in iOS 8; provisioning profiles can't be updated stand alone. You will need to build a new version in Xcode.